# Decorator pattern: Is it required that all decorators add value despite the sequence of initialization

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, decorator

I have a question about the decorator and his sequence of initializing. 
Is it required the each decorator can be extended by each other decorator, or is it also oke if there are restrictions with extending the decoraters. For example:

```
Subject subject = new Subject();
decorator       = new ErrorHandlingDecorator(subject); //Extends for error handling, when error is detected it interupt the current thread.
decorator       = new ExecuteFunctionDecorator(decorator); //Execute a function and run the executeFunction() on his parent.

decorator.executeFunction();
```

Here the `ExecuteFunctionDecorator` can pass the result to the `ErrorHandlingDecorator` because it first execute the function. But when you initialize it like the code below the `ErrorHandlingDecorator` is useless because it first checks the error and then execute the function.

```
Subject subject  = new Subject();
decorator        = new ExecuteFunctionDecorator(subject); //Execute a function and run the executeFunction() on his parent.
decorator        = new ErrorHandlingDecorator(decorator); //Extends for error handling, when error is detected it interupt the current thread.
```

So my question is: is this example still a decorator or is it required that all decorators add value despite the sequence of initialization, or is ok that a decorator can be meaningless after a 'incorrect' initialization?

Any related information is welcome.

Regards,

Comment: Design patterns are guidelines, don't worry about those tiny adaptations to make it fit more within your model. Nobody is going to say that you shouldn't do something that makes sense just because the theoretical model of the decorator pattern is a little different.

Comment: Why do you need an `ExecuteFunctionDecorator` ? To me `executeFunction()` should be an abstract method in `Subject`. Client code that manipulates the object doesn't know that it's decorated and will just call `executeFunction()` on it. You don't need an additional Decorator for behavior that the original abstraction, and all its family of subclasses, are already supposed to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical example for a Decorator (I think it was from the GOF book) is a widget or panel from a UI application that can be enhanced (or decorated) with further styling (e.g. borders).

Imagine two different decorators, one decorating your rectangular widget with a 1pixel-sized border and another, using a 5pixel-sized dash border.

Do you expect (1) `new DashedBorder(new Border(new Panel()))` to look the same as (2) `new Border(new DashedBorder(new Panel()))`? I would not. In the first case I would expect a 1pixel-sized border encapsulated by a 5pixel-sized dashed border and in the second case a vice-versa result.

Decorators do what they are called. They decorate your object. Decorating an object with two different things can lead to the same result but they do not have to.